# Spyder conflict with PyQt, Spyder won't start

Tags: python, pyqt5, spyder

I made a mistake... I tried to install a package to write mathematical equations which contained the last version of Qt5.15.2. But now I can't start spyder because it seems that it can't choose between the old version and the new version of Qt... I have to say I don't know much about this Qt stuff.

OS Version: macOS 12.7.1 (21G920)

Here is the error message from Anaconda.Navigator:

```
objc[40030]: Class QMacAutoReleasePoolTracker is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.15.2.dylib (0x101f012b8) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x10d9e7198). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[40030]: Class QT_ROOT_LEVEL_POOL__THESE_OBJECTS_WILL_BE_RELEASED_WHEN_QAPP_GOES_OUT_OF_SCOPE is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.15.2.dylib (0x101f01330) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x10d9e7210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[40030]: Class KeyValueObserver is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.15.2.dylib (0x101f01358) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x10d9e7238). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[40030]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.15.2.dylib (0x101f013a8) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x10d9e7288). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[40030]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.5.15.2.dylib (0x10131b478) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x1024ea540). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[40030]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5PrintSupport.5.15.2.dylib (0x10131b4f0) and /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt5/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x1024ea5b8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pythonw: line 3: 40030 Abort trap: 6 /opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

My first test was to remove anaconda using the documentation provided: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/uninstall/
But this didn't solve the issue
I tried to go after the Qt5.15.2 folder to remove it manually but it didn't help...
I am out of options and this has been going on for several days now.
I would greatly appreciate some help from you guys.
Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is not a code related issue... This is a conflict based on two occurence of PyQt... Any chance anyone knows how to remove Qt5.15.2?